# convert Function so as to give 3rd state

Tags: vba, excel

Would it be easy to convert the following function so that instead of just 0 or 1 it gave the following three outputs:

0 - means file closed
1 - means file is already open
2 - means file does not exist

Here's the Function

```
Function IsFileReadOnlyOpen(FileName As String)

Dim iFilenum As Long
Dim iErr As Long

On Error Resume Next
iFilenum = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum
Close iFilenum
iErr = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case iErr
 Case 0:    IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 0
 Case 70:   IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 1
 Case Else: Error iErr
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Just a quick comment, but you'd do well to use Enumerations for this sort of thing... They make your code easier to read - espcially by other developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add this at the beginning of your function:

```
If Dir(FileName) = "" Then 'File does not exist
    IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 2
    Exit Function 'Or not - I don't know if you want to create the file or exit in that case.
End If
```

I agree with the comment that you should use enum to make it easier to understand.

PS: As commented by [Martin Milan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451758/convert-function-so-as-to-give-3rd-state/10451898#comment13495405_10451898) this might cause issues. Alternatively, you can use this:

```
With New FileSystemObject
    If .FileExists(FileName) Then
        IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 2
        Exit Function 'Or not - I don't know if you want to create the file or exit in that case.
    End If
End With
```

Comment: The only warning I would issue about using Dir() is that you can't use it from inside a loop where it is already being used for another purpose. I used to write VB6 in a former life, and ended up writing methods that went out to WINAPI to get around that little restriction...

Comment: @assylias: Martin's point is that there is no way for the function to know whether it is being called from inside a loop that uses Dir().  And there is no way for us to know if the OP will be using it that way.  The global scope nature of Dir() can lead to very hard to diagnose bugs....I've been there.

Comment: Martin's point is all the more important because the function WILL work correctly in isolation.  And the bug will not show up within the function, but in the calling procedure, where it may not be obvious that this function is what is actually causing the problem.

Comment: @mwolfe02 Thanks for your comment - I have amended my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FileSystemObject to test for the existence of a file explicitly, if that is your difficulty.

You'll need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library though in order to do that, and I tend to try to avoid that.

You can use FindFirstFile from the Win32API to test this, but that's a little more involved - and also won't help you if the user is actually running on a Mac...

Answer (score 0):

have ended up with:

```
Enum FileOpenState
        ExistsAndClosed = 0
        ExistsAndOpen = 1
        NotExists = 2
End Enum

Function IsFileReadOnlyOpen(FileName As String)

With New FileSystemObject
      If Not .FileExists(FileName) Then
              IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 2  '  NotExists = 2
              Exit Function 'Or not - I don't know if you want to create the file or exit in that case.
      End If
End With

Dim iFilenum As Long
Dim iErr As Long

On Error Resume Next
        iFilenum = FreeFile()
        Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum
        Close iFilenum
        iErr = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case iErr
    Case 0:    IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 0
    Case 70:   IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 1
    Case Else: IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 1 'Error iErr
End Select

End Function
```